# POST: 405 (Method Not Allowed) but it doesn't tell about errors

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, localhost

**This is my form id:**

```
<form id="signupForm" method="POST" class="pt-3" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                @csrf
```

**And this is the ajax I use:**

```
function loginUser()
            {
              // console.log('here');
                // e.preventDefault();
                var formData  = new FormData(jQuery('#signupForm')[0]);

                $.ajax({
                    url:"home",
                    type:"POST",
                    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
     },
                    data:formData,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                      // console.log(data.data.role);
                      // return;
                      // window.location = "http://localhost/dashboard_new/public/home";
                      if(data.code==200)
                      {
                        window.location = "http://localhost/dashboard_new/public/home";
                      }
                      if(data.code==400)
                      {
                           $('#form_submit_error').modal('show');
                            setTimeout(function() {$('#form_submit_error').modal('hide');}, 2000);
                      }

                    }, error: function (xhr, status, error)
                    {

                        // console.log(xhr.responseJSON.errors);
                        $.each(xhr.responseJSON.errors,function(key,item)
                        {

                    if(data.code==400)
                                {
                                  $('#form_submit_error').modal('show');
                            setTimeout(function() {$('#form_submit_error').modal('hide');}, 2000);
                                }
                        })
                    }
              });
            }
```

**This is the route:**

```
Route::view('/','welcome');
Route::get('welcome', 'HomeController@loginUser');
```

[This is the screenshot of submitted data for login, the message occurs "submitted", but it doesn't read my database and even doesn't respond..even in inspect element it says that
**POST http://localhost:8000/home 405 (Method Not Allowed)**
,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxZsb.png)

Answer (score 1):

Actually Laravel says that there is not such a **method** that you called. Its simply because of the `get` method which you defined in Laravel router. Define a route like this:

```
Route::post('login', 'HomeController@loginUser');
```

and in your Ajax request you should change `url` property to `login`:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"login", // <= here
    type:"POST",
    ...
```

Comment: It dosen't work, same error...vendor.bundle.base.js:2 POST http://localhost:8000/home 405 (Method Not Allowed)
send @ vendor.bundle.base.js:2
ajax @ vendor.bundle.base.js:2
loginUser @ (index):220
onclick @ (index):143

Comment: Look! you are sending login request to `/home`. Type login route in the javascript code.

Comment: @IrtazaAli Method not allow is already described itself. The method you are requesting is not allowed. Check for the **method** and **path** in your server application's routes.